# Action Listener on Image View

Tags: android

How to apply action listener on Image view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in your onCreate method, this is quite easy :

```
//create you ImageView :
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itsId);
//set the listener
iv.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then let your activity implement `OnClickListener` and add unimplemented method. finally, add the behaviour you need in the `onClick()` method

Comment: For some reason my ClickListener only gets invoked the first time.  It doesn't react on subsequent clicks...

Comment: I suggest you post a new question to get an answer to yours. Comment is not the place to ask new-unrelated questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

Type this inside onCreate() :

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid);

image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //actions
    } 

});
```